# Htaccess in root folder config

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website running on the root folder of my host  /index.php

I wan't to Block an IP from accessing my website (I know how to do it)

But I wan't to redeirect him to another page to let him know he got banned.

The probleme is that he is banned from every subdomains to so he is not able to view the

banned.html page I made, I need help to fix this.

/index.php (Main website)

/banned/user_name.html  (Reason and ban notification for the banned user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place a .htaccess file in a sub-folder, its directives will override the ones that you have in your site main folder... so if you just place another .htaccess file inside of your banned folder that allows him to view that page, all should be well. I'm also willing to bet there are exclusions you could place in your .htaccess file in the root folder, but this may be a simple option for you.

Comment: Thank you! Creating a new htaccess for my sub-folder allowing the banned IP into it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.1$   # Put here IP you want to block
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/banned/user_name.html$
RewriteRule .* /banned/user_name.html [R=301,L]
```